# Finitely presentable objects in presheaves

Tags: functors, hom-functor, locally-presentable-categories

How can be described finitely presentable objects in $${\mathbf{Set}^{\cal A}}^{op}$$ for $\cal A$ small ?

Comment: Is my question so trivial to downvote without an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the split subobjects of finite colimits of hom functors, since any presheaf is a directed colimit
of finite colimits of hom functors.